# Access point initial scan

Tags: c, linux, wireless

Is there a way to trigger a scan on an AP before it is initialized?

I tried to call a scan in /net/wireless/cfg.c start_ap() function, but the system hangs. What could be a better option for this? I use linux version 3.12.18

Answer (score 0):

You should do that in user space; before setting the AP mode you can run a bunch of "iw" commands in a shell script to set up client mode and run a scan. Then you enter AP mode.

Once you are in AP mode you cannot trigger a multichannel scan because the clients would see the AP disappearing (from the channel were they associated).